# Comparing strings with objects in c#/XNA

Tags: xna, c#, xml

I have an XML file which is split up using pipes "|". I have some code in a question class that splits up the XML files "Items" as so..

```
 List<string> questionComponents = newquestionString.Split('|').ToList<string>();

        questionString = questionComponents[0];
        apple = questionComponents[1];
        pear = questionComponents[2];
        orange = questionComponents[3];

        correctAnswer = Int32.Parse(questionComponents[4]);
```

I want to compare these components with objects which are instantiated in my Game1 class (three fruit - apple, pear, orange). So how do I do this?

A friend helped me get this far. I have no idea how to do this, and after searching google with no luck I've resulted in asking here to you lovely people.

Thanks in advance :D

**EDIT: To clear things up...**

I have three objects called apple, pear and orange and I want to associate these objects with the strings which are shown in the XML file for each component of the strings. The question string displays a question, [1] answer 1, [2] answer 2, [3] answer [3].

And then I need a way to compare the answer to the object that is eaten in the game..

Comment: I am confused. So your apple, pear, and orange are strings(say "apple", "pear", "orange") but what objects do you want to compare with?

Comment: I'm 99% sure you're doing something horribly wrong if you're using a string like `Somequestion|apple|pear|orange` inside an XML file...

Comment: @Jonathan: Such formats are extremely common for i18n because it keeps all the strings in-context, translators can provide more or fewer alternatives if appropriate, and because it maps cleanly onto every k/v pair i18n system out there.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have some kind of `Orange` object, some kind of `Pear` object, and some kind of `Apple` object, in each class [override the ToString method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If you have some generic `Fruit` or `Answer` object, consider passing a string in the constructor and returning that string in the `ToString` method.

EDIT: Since you've now clarified, I would go with Jonathan's idea of having a `Name` or `Answer` property; then you can do:

```
if(object.Answer == questionComponent)
//do stuff
```

And ToString does not turn the object into a string. It simply returns a user-defined (if you choose to override) string for the object - for the Ints it is "42", and for bools it is "true" or "false". No conversion occurs.

Comment: Alternately give it a `Name` property.

Comment: I was going for the override of ToString since it seems somewhat standard.

Comment: Fair enough. For real, palpable objects, though, it seems unintuitive to me - turning a fruit into a string vs getting its name.

Comment: I think it really depends on whether he needs just a name for this, or for other matters.

Comment: I don't need to change the objects into strings, I need the objects to be associated with the answers to each question that displays on the screen, so that when a user picks an answer - the game knows if it was the correct one based on the fruit

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, it *sounds* like all you're trying to do is be able to look up some concrete object based on a string that you get from a data file? Couldn't you use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) for this, as in:

```
Fruit apple = new Apple();
Fruit orange = new Orange();

Dictionary<string,Fruit> map = new Dictionary<string,Fruit>();
map["apple"] = apple;
map["orange"] = orange;
```

and then later you can get the user's answer/input:

```
string input = ...
Fruit result;
if(map.TryGetValue(input, out result)) {
  // `fruit` now holds the fruit object the user selected.
} else {
  // User input did not correspond to a known fruit.
}
```

But I'm still not convinced I'm understanding your question properly.

Comment: The user controls a snake which eats either an apple, pear or orange depending on the answer to a particular question that appears on the screen. All I want to do is compare the objects with the sections that has been broken down in the XML file and then compare the answer eaten by the snake with the correct answer which is part [4] of the components.

Understand?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the range of possible strings is limited, so why not just use identifiers in the form of Enums, which you can parse from the string, and set that identifier into the answers and the fruits?

```
public enum AnswerType
{
  Apple,
  Pear,
  Banana
}
```

Store the answers in a dictionary mapping ids to answers (casting enum to int for the key), plus the correct answer's id, and now you can know which answer was picked each time, checking the eaten fruit's id, and if the answer was right.